# Is it possible to separate limits of multivariable functions in such a manner?

Tags: calculus

If we have a function like this:

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)}\frac{y \ln y}{x}$

Can we separate it like so, separating the variables?

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)}\frac{y \ln y}{x} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{x} \cdot \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{ln y}{\frac{1}{y}}$

Is this valid?  I can apply L'Hopitals rule now, to get the answer L=0

Comment: Yes. But before the edit it wasn't right since $\lim_{y\to0}\ln y$ didn't exist.

Comment: You can separate it like this, but L'Hopials cannot be formally applied even though it will give the right result.

Comment: @NikolayGromov If we can't use L'Hopitals in this limit, is it acceptable to create another limit of the exact same function in terms of another variable and use L'Hopitals rule on that, concluding the limit is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the limits can be separated if & only if they individually exist

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{y\ln y}{x}=\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{\ln y}{\frac{1}{y}}\cdot \lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{1}{x}$$ 
$$=\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{\ln y}{\frac{1}{y}}\cdot (1)=\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{\ln y}{\frac{1}{y}}$$ Applying L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form  $$=\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}\frac{\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{-1}{y^2}}$$
$$=-\lim_{(x, y)\to (1, 0)}(y)=0$$